# Convert byte[] to base64 and ASCII in Python

Tags: python, base64

How do I to convert and array of byte to base64 string and/or ASCII.

I can do this easily in C#, but can't seem to do this in Python

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The simplest approach would be: Array to json to base64:

```
import json
import base64

data = [0, 1, 0, 0, 83, 116, -10]
dataStr = json.dumps(data)

base64EncodedStr = base64.b64encode(dataStr.encode('utf-8'))
print(base64EncodedStr)

print('decoded', base64.b64decode(base64EncodedStr))
```

Prints out:

```
>>> WzAsIDEsIDAsIDAsIDgzLCAxMTYsIC0xMF0=
>>> ('decoded', '[0, 1, 0, 0, 83, 116, -10]')  # json.loads here !
```

... another option could be using [bitarray module](https://github.com/ilanschnell/bitarray).

Comment: the 'dataStr = json.dumps(data)' is not needed when your list is a byte array, you can directly encode it.

Comment: For further information, to cast `base64EncodedStr ` to string, add `.decode('utf-8')` chained method to it. So `base64EncodedStr.decode('utf-8')` returns a string

Answer (score 26):

This honestly should be all that you need: https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/base64.html

In this example you can see where they convert bytes to base64 and decode it back to bytes again:

```
>>> import base64
>>> encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')
>>> encoded
b'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk'
>>> data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
>>> data
b'data to be encoded'
```

You may need to first take your array and turn it into a string with join, like this:

```
>>> my_joined_string_of_bytes = "".join(["my", "cool", "strings", "of", "bytes"])
```

Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. However I'm starting with this kind of data array('b',[0, 1, 0, 0, 83, 116, -10, ....]) how can I implement with this approach?

Comment: @Light You can just give an `array` to `b64encode`.  Does that not work?  Update the question to show exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I see the the .join part only works for string types and have to coerce my data to string TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: @Light I don't know what you're doing, but why do you need to `.join`?  You can concatenate `array`s with `+`.  If you want a string-like API, use `bytearray`s instead of `array`s (though `bytearray`s expect unsigned bytes, like an `array('B', [])`).