# LLDP module in SCAPY produce malformed packets

Tags: python, scapy, ethernet

I am using scapy.contrib.lldp library to craft an LLDP packet, with the following fields:

- Chassis ID (l1)
- Port ID (l2)
- Time to live (l3)
- System name (l4)
- Generic Organisation Specific - custom data 1 (l5)
- Generic Organisation Specific - custom data 2 (l6)
- End of LLDP (l7)

The options for each field comes from a csv file imported as DataFrame and I use the library class for each field.

The problem I have is that after I craft the packet (p=ethernet/l1/l2/l3/l4/l5/l6/l7) the l6 field has the double amount of bytes it is supposed to have, from the read data. I also tried to set a fixed value but the problem persists.

Below is a sample of the packet in wireshark (ok packet and malformed packet), the DataFrame and relevant code.

[image: wireshark capture (ok packet and malformed packet)]

| Layer | Field | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ethernet | dst | 01:23:00:00:00:01 |
| Ethernet | src | 32:cb:cd:7b:5a:47 |
| Ethernet | type | 35020 |
| LLDPDUChassisID | _type | 1 |
| LLDPDUChassisID | _length | 7 |
| LLDPDUChassisID | subtype | 4 |
| LLDPDUChassisID | family | None |
| LLDPDUChassisID | id | 00:00:00:00:00:01 |
| LLDPDUPortID | _type | 2 |
| LLDPDUPortID | _length | 2 |
| LLDPDUPortID | subtype | 7 |
| LLDPDUPortID | family | None |
| LLDPDUPortID | id | 1 |
| LLDPDUTimeToLive | _type | 3 |
| LLDPDUTimeToLive | _length | 2 |
| LLDPDUTimeToLive | ttl | 4919 |
| LLDPDUSystemName | _type | 5 |
| LLDPDUSystemName | _length | 10 |
| LLDPDUSystemName | system_name | openflow:1 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | _type | 127 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | _length | 16 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | org_code | 9953 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | subtype | 0 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | data | openflow:1:1 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | _type | 127 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | _length | 20 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | org_code | 9953 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | subtype | 1 |
| LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific | data | **b'`\xafE\x16\t\xa0#5\x02\x7f\xd5\p\xf7\x11A'** |
| LLDPDUEndOfLLDPDU | _type | 0 |
| LLDPDUEndOfLLDPDU | _length | 0 |

```
def getlldppack(host_2,ifa):
    lim = 1
    log = "/root/log.log"
    file = "/root/dic_"+str(host_2)+"_"+str(lim)+".csv"
    while lim<5:
        try:
            lldp1 = pd.read_csv(file)
        except:
            with open(log,'a') as lf:
                lf.write("error when reading the packet "+file+" for count "+str(lim)+"\n")
            time.sleep(8)
        else:
            lldp1 = lldp1.iloc[: , 1:]
            e1=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='Ethernet')&(lldp1['Field']=='dst')].iloc[0,2]
            e2=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='Ethernet')&(lldp1['Field']=='src')].iloc[0,2]
            e3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='Ethernet')&(lldp1['Field']=='type')].iloc[0,2])
            e = Ether(dst=e1, src=e2, type=e3)
            a1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUChassisID')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            a2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUChassisID')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
            a3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUChassisID')&(lldp1['Field']=='subtype')].iloc[0,2])
            a4=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUChassisID')&(lldp1['Field']=='family')].iloc[0,2]
            a5=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUChassisID')&(lldp1['Field']=='id')].iloc[0,2]
            b1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUPortID')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            b2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUPortID')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
            b3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUPortID')&(lldp1['Field']=='subtype')].iloc[0,2])
            b4=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUPortID')&(lldp1['Field']=='family')].iloc[0,2]
            b5=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUPortID')&(lldp1['Field']=='id')].iloc[0,2])
            c1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUTimeToLive')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            c2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUTimeToLive')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
            c3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUTimeToLive')&(lldp1['Field']=='ttl')].iloc[0,2])
            d1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUSystemName')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            d2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUSystemName')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
            d3=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUSystemName')&(lldp1['Field']=='system_name')].iloc[0,2]
            e1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            e2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
            e3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='org_code')].iloc[0,2])
            e4=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='subtype')].iloc[0,2])
            e5=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='data')].iloc[0,2]
            f1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[1,2])
            f2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[1,2])
            f3=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='org_code')].iloc[1,2])
            f4=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='subtype')].iloc[1,2])
            f5=lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific')&(lldp1['Field']=='data')].iloc[1,2]
            g1=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUEndOfLLDPDU')&(lldp1['Field']=='_type')].iloc[0,2])
            g2=int(lldp1.loc[(lldp1['Layer']=='LLDPDUEndOfLLDPDU')&(lldp1['Field']=='_length')].iloc[0,2])
           
           
            l1 = LLDPDUChassisID(_type=a1,_length=a2,subtype=a3,family=a4,id=a5)
            l2 = LLDPDUPortID(_type=b1,_length=b2,subtype=b3,family=b4,id=str(b5))
            l3 = LLDPDUTimeToLive(_type=c1,_length=c2,ttl=c3)
            auxo=d3
            l4 = LLDPDUSystemName(_type=d1,_length=d2,system_name=auxo)
            auxo=e5
            l5 = LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific(_type=e1,_length=e2,org_code=e3,subtype=e4,data=auxo)
            auxa=f5[2:-1]
            l6 = LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific(_type=f1,_length=f2,org_code=f3,subtype=f4,data=auxa)
            l7 = LLDPDUEndOfLLDPDU(_type=0,_length=0)
            lldpu_layer = LLDPDU()
            lldpu_layer = l1/l2/l3/l4/l5/l6/l7
            
            pack = e/lldpu_layer
            
            flag = False
            sendp(pack,count=1, iface=ifa)
            flag = True
            lim = lim +1

            with open(log,'a') as lf:
                lf.write('read packet '+file+"\n")
```

I tried changing the data types, also fixed the data in the option "data" of
LLDPDUGenericOrganisationSpecific, but it did not work.

I hope I can have a packet with the right length so it reproduces exactly the non-crafted packet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the encoding, it was wrong since I wrote the data in the data frame.

The solution was to encode with base64 BEFORE saving the information in the data frame, I used this explanation: [Convert byte[] to base64 and ASCII in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920799/convert-byte-to-base64-and-ascii-in-python#43923197)

That changed my data from *b'`\xafE\x16\t\xa0#5\x02\x7f\xd5\p\xf7\x11A'* to *b'YK9FFgmgIzUCf9VccPcRQQ=='*.
Then, when I had to put it in the field, I removed the b'' characters and then did the decoding, as said in the link.